# JOSSO gateway deployment on Weblogic 10

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x, josso

I'm trying to work out a proof of concept with SSO using JOSSO. However, i'm having issue installing JOSSO on my server, which is a Weblogic 10 instance.

I have managed to install JOSSO in my domain. However when i start the server, there's an error saying it failed to parse one of the configuration XML file on the server because the file is not found. I double check the directory and the XML file is actually there.

The exception:

> SEVERE: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [josso-gateway-config.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [josso-gateway-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Also another issue i'm facing is, on my production server, the webapp directory is actually in a separate partition as the Weblogic home folder. I found that the JOSSO installation program will assume that both of them are located in the same directory. Is there any way i can customize this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it solved. Posting it here in case can help someone.

Due to the setup of my weblogic environment, i have decided to explode the war file, and deploy it as an exploded directory. Steps i followed:

1. Use WinRAR and unrar the war file into a directory
2. Copy all the xml configuration files into the classes folder
3. Rename one of the stores configuration file into josso-gateway-stores.xml
4. Deploy the exploded directory